# Can we cool Earth by shooting powerful lasers into space?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy-conservation, planets, climate-science

In a sense, the climate change discussion revolves around the unwanted warming of the earth's atmosphere as a whole.

It seems a bit too obvious to be true, but could we cool the atmosphere by simply shooting that unwanted energy somewhere else?

Energy might be collected from remote expanses where it would otherwise be somewhat pointless to harvest it due to lack of habitability and resulting anticipated losses due to transmission (ocean surface, ???)

If so, what would be a good place to shoot it?

Comment: How would the lasers be powered?

Comment: Either with energy gathered from renewable sources or with nuclear power.

Comment: So the nuclear reactors would be generating energy not previously in the atmosphere, and then getting rid of it.  How does this reduce global warming?

Comment: Point. So it would really have to be collected from climate -- see edit to OP

Comment: I don’t understand the harsh reaction to this question. Moving thermal energy from one system to another (here, from Earth to space) is what a [heat pump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_pump) does. And a commercial heat pump can dump its waste heat into the high-temperature or the low-temperature reservoir — you don’t move your unit indoors when you switch from cooling to heating mode. I suspect laser emission into space doesn’t support this cycle, but the reason is a nontrivial bit of introductory thermodynamics. I’ve removed some dismissive comments.

Comment: Just shading the earth would be a lot more practical. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_sunshade - short of you know, just stop emitting more CO2 than we consume.

Comment: @MikeWise I understand what you mean, but humans don't "consume" CO2. Forests and oceans do.

Comment: Whole-earth "we"

Comment: Is this question perhaps inspired by the "refrigeration lasers" from several of David Brin's novels? Those are unfortunately nonsense, lasers can be used to cool other things, but they can not convert ambient heat into laser light. Rather the opposite, lasers of significant power need lots of cooling.

Comment: Mirrors would be a lot more effective…

Comment: Try to avoid hitting alien civilisations with anger management issues.

Comment: As the problem is not that the earth has too much laser light, but too much heat. So you would have to convert the heat into laser energy first. How would you do that?

Answer (score 40):

Your idea to cool the Earth by shooting photons off into space is actually what already happens now!  However, instead of a laser, the Earth cools itself by blackbody radiation.  The Earth radiates a $\mathrm{\approx 300~^\circ K}$ (room temperature) black body spectrum with a peak at $\mathrm{kT=\frac{1}{40}eV}$ which is just a little redder than an infrared laser.  The Earth also receives radiation from the Sun and a $\mathrm{3 ~^\circ K}$ blackbody spectrum from the cosmic microwave background (CMBR).  Overall the Earth is in equilibrium (its temperature is constant) so it radiates as much power as it receives.

The total power radiated by the Earth is:

$$\mathrm{Power=4\pi(R_{earth})^2\sigma T^4=2.3\times 10^5\quad Terawatts}$$

It would take some really big CW lasers to compete with this!!

Comment: Also, the greenhouse effect is largely down to the fact that, because GHGs increase the lapse rate, they cause the effective surface at which heat radiates into space to be cooler, so Earth less readily radiates heat into space than previously.

Comment: Yes, we can just cover the Earth with [ultrawhite emissivity-engineered paint with "remarkable daytime subambient radiative cooling"](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/51733/12102).

Comment: What does CW mean?

Comment: To put this number in context: worldwide electricity consumption is about 2.5 Tw, so total radiative cooling is about 100 000 times mankind's total electricity consumption. (btw, earth is not *quite* in thermal equilibrium; we call this global warming)

Comment: @Pedro    CW="continuous wave".  The laser continuously puts out a terawatt as opposed to the usual pulsed laser which puts out a terawatt for only $10^{-12}$ second (thus making an average power of only 1 watt).

Comment: I doubt that the earth radiates at 300K - wouldn't one expect a part of that radiation to be absorbed by the atmosphere?

Comment: The Earth also produces heat via radioactive fission and has residual heat from the gravitational energy its constituting matter had before it was concentrated into this ball, cf. the postulated [iron catastrophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_catastrophe). I suppose there is enough residual heat and ongoing fission left to shift it measurably out of a true radiative equilibrium: Earth must shed more energy than it receives.

Comment: Duh, just use the Death Star to shoot all that unwanted energy into space.... and you will get a nice fireworks show too... ;)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: Yes, that's a large part of the greenhouse problem. Of course, the atmosphere itself also radiates. In the context of a Physics.SE answer this is close enough.

Comment: @meriton or conversely, mankind has managed to harness 1/100000 of the total power available on Earth - impressive.

Comment: @MSalters Given that blackbody radiation scales like $T^4$, this can make a big difference!

Answer (score 26):

Ambient heat is low grade energy. You can't effectively harness it to do work (which is a transfer of energy. i.e. powering laser which itself is a machine to transfer energy) because it has nowhere to flow effectively. If you could, we wouldn't have energy problems. At all. You could then harness waste heat from machines and make perpetual motion machines (or nearly so), or easily make it flow on its own somewhere else if there is too much (which was the goal of a fancy laser to begin with). In reality, it's like trying to power a dam or drain water away when the elevation everywhere is the same.

You would need something with the same fundamental concept of  a refrigerator which uses an input of high-grade energy (electricity) to do work. That work is shoving low-grade energy from one place to another because the low-grade energy doesn't want to flow anywhere on its own. The laser in this case acts like an active heatsink to shunt energy away once it's collected.

The catch is that this consumes good energy you have which might be scarce, and in itself produces waste heat when used too. So you also need a mechanism to get that new waste heat into the laser or if you can't then some way to move that heat away without the laser (which was your original problem) lest you have a net heat build-up.  It's almost a Catch-22.

Not impossible but tough. You would almost need a space elevator of a refrigerator to shunt heat up into machinery in space where you could do something to dissipate where the waste heat from the process could also be dissipated without immediately ending back on Earth. Forget the laser. Could be as "simple" as a *massive* glowing red or white hot heatsink inefficiently radiating heat away into the vacuum of space (and hopefully not back at Earth) via blackbody radiation. I'll remind you why the sun glows at this point), but you can see the issues.

Actually what I described is basically what a split air conditioning system is but on a space elevator scale. They are structurally arranged the same way for the same reason. The split prevents heat of the machinery from feeding back to the area you are trying to cool.

Comment: To some extent wind power utilizes the uneven distribution of ambient heat. But, better to just use it as power in the first place rather than only sending ~10% off into space while turning the other 90% back into heat.

Comment: @JonCuster Well, ambiency depends on the size of the locale you are considering I suppose since that defines your closed system and where you can shunt uneven heat distributions around (if any). So if we're trying to cool Earth that is our collective ambient and closed system. A civilization that has structures between planets might not have that limitation and just use Earth has a heat dump. Like if your ambient is Las Vegas you might not care if your giant AC dome over the city heats up Seattle in the process.

Comment: I was primarily addressing your first few sentences - the wind exists because of natural unevenness in the weather so is a way to harness low-grade heat and effectively harness it to do work. Using the laser still isn't a good thing to do.

Comment: @JonCuster Well there's low grade, then there's *low-grade*, even amongst ambient heat which is low-grade in general.

Comment: Luckily, we do have a ready supply of high-grade energy (the sun) and an endless low-grade reservoir to exhaust our unwanted low-grade energy to. There's just some air inthe way.

Comment: The suggestion of a massive glowing heat sink reminds me of the retractable cooling fins on Trantor in Asimov’s Foundation series.

Answer (score 17):

Your proposal is to increase the effective albedo of the Earth, and in principle it could work. No need for the giant lasers though—probably more efficient and much cheaper just to use mirrors.

Comment: Or block the arrival of some of the sun's light with reflectors near the sun, although the question was about something slightly different

Comment: and/or [increase it's thermal infrared emissivity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/650490/can-we-cool-earth-by-shooting-powerful-lasers-into-space#comment1461074_650534)

Answer (score 12):

Nice idea... but lasers get their power from electricity.  If we had lots of spare electricity, we could stop generating more and reduce the energy output from coal or gas powered power stations.

So, yes it would be good for the planet to use that electricity to heat our homes etc...but no point really shooting it off into space.

Comment: If one considers the question more broadly, it’s about using a smaller amount of electrical energy to immediately eject a larger amount of thermal energy, in the manner of a global heat pump, perhaps. (This doesn’t violate any thermodynamics laws, despite a number of cavalier comments.) Proposing to reduce coal burning somewhat misses the point; with excess energy, this would have already been done, and it doesn’t provide *immediate* cooling.

Comment: What would you propose to eject from the earth?  If the laser proposal doesn't work, would it be hot matter?  If so, how would it be heated, how efficient would the ejection mechanism be etc...if it was already hot, such as in the earth's core, it's just releasing heat into habitable area - all seems totally impractical.

Comment: @JohnHunter See the space elevator split AC in my answer. The Earth is just a big room with walls that are really difficult to drill a hole through to install the pipe for your split AC system. Doesn't mean it's impossible though.

Comment: It depends whether the discussion is about 'in principle' or 'in practice'.  In principle heat could be removed from the earth, back to the laser method, powered by electricity from a hydro-electric dam.  In practice to make a heat pump to transfer heat from one place to another is best when the sink is not too hot, and if not too hot would not radiate much.  Add to this the greenhouse effect that making all the 'elevator' parts/transport etc...entails and it still seems totally impractical, even if possible in theory.

Answer (score 8):

> ... could we cool the atmosphere by simply shooting that unwanted energy somewhere else?

Yes, but only by making our problems worse than they are already. A heat pump removes unwanted heat (that is how a refrigerator works) *but* it takes energy to make a heat pump work. Either this energy comes from non-renewable resources - which just generates more heat and makes our energy problems worse - or it comes from renewable resources such as solar power. But using energy from renewable resources to export heat that you have generated by consuming non-renewable resources makes no sense - just replace the non-renewable resources with the renewable resources in the first place.

Here is an analogy - you have lit a fire in your room to run a steam engine which generates all your electricity. But the fire is making the room too hot and you want to run an air conditioning unit to cool the room down. You could build a bigger fire to generate more electricity to run the air conditioning unit - but that makes your problem worse. Or you could install solar panels to generate electricity to power the air conditioning unit - but if you have solar panels why do you still need your fire and steam engine ?

Comment: I understand this, as long as you understand how much power is lost in transmission using current methods (Up to 50%)

Comment: "if you have solar panels why do you still need your fire and steam engine ?" is the big one

Comment: @user253751 Do existing solar panels get warm while they do their job? ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Like other answers say... Your problem is that the act of forcibly  pumping energy one place to another, beyond what nature itself would do, takes additional energy.

So for example, moving the warmth from inside your fridge to outside it, costs extra energy. Informally (not literally to scale), you can think that the fridge interior loses 100 units of heat energy, so it does cool down. But the outside - the room and ultimately the planet as a whole - gains 110 units of heat energy:  100 units moved from inside the fridge, but also an extra 10 units from the work the pump must do, to move that 100 units from inside to outside. Overall the planet heats up.

Your lasers will do the same. They will send 100 units of heat energy into space, but to do so will require an extra 10,000 units of heat into the room, or the planet generally. (Not literally to scale). Big lasers take a **lot** of energy to fire up.

Similarly with anything collecting low grade heat and concentrating it as high density heat, or collecting solar energy to pump heat around. These all pretty much will add more heat to the planet than they remove, as they move heat round.

If you want to remove heat from earth, the best ways are 1) stop adding heat, or be more energy efficient and reduce the energy you use on earth, 2) make it easier for heat to escape (reduce heat-retaining mechanisms:  CO2, methane, etc), 3) move energy consumption into space.

Comment: This honestly may take the cake for explicitly answering the question I really meant to ask.

Comment: A good answer, but for solution 3) to work you would also need to get rid of the huge losses in transmission. My understanding is that a geosynchronous orbit is 35,786 kilometers (22,236 miles) above the Earth, so presumably this is where you would be generating power. Also, you would need to be able to manufacture the parts for your power station in space from materials available in space, as otherwise the energy required to move them up there (over 28 kW-hours per kilo of material) would outweigh the benefits for a long long time to come.

Comment: @clayRay -- you are misunderstanding, I think. I said **"move energy consumption into space"**. Not energy _production_. For (3), I was thinking of concepts around moving energy intensive manufacturing, extraction, and refining, off earth -- not moving mere energy generation off earth. Also note that moving energy production to space doesn't do much to reduce earth heating, if you immediately send that energy down to earth anyhow.

Comment: @Stilez - sorry, I misunderstood. I suppose if we had some sort of space elevator, it would be relatively cheap, energy-wise to bring the refined or manufactured materials down from space. Perhaps you could even generate power in the process, something similar to regenerative braking in trains.

Answer (score 5):

Cheap and effective method: We should paint roofs and streets white.

Besides, a small part of the Sahara would currently be enough to supply humans with electricity from solar cells. On the rest of the Sahara there could be solar cells to power your lasers. But this is only possible if the power loss of cells and lasers that escapes into the environment is less than the part of the sunlight that does not leave the earth as reflected radiation nad heats the earth.

Comment: ironically (or not?) solar panels have a lower albedo that most surfaces, so while some fraction of the sunlight hitting them is converted to electricity (~30% *best* case) it's actually introducing more heat to the Earth even assuming the work the electricity itself does mostly doesn't wind up as heat (which probably isn't true).

Comment: Unfortunately the White Roof solution has [been cast into doubt](https://www.climatecentral.org/blogs/white-roofs-may-increase-global-warming), although it may work well close to the equator.

Comment: Isn't the basic question whether a laser sending out  *n* Watts to the distance radiates less than *n* Watt of heat to the local environment?

Answer (score 0):

From comments:

> How would the lasers be powered? – DJohnM

> Either with energy gathered from renewable sources or with nuclear power –  DJG

The answer very much depends on the source of energy.

Shooting lasers into the space will transfer *energy* out from Earth.

For example let's consider a nuclear plant using $^{235}$U. $^{235}$U stores energy in form of bonding energy of the nucleus. By using uranium in a plant, you release this energy. Part might be used for your laser, part will be inevitably dissipated in form of heat on Earth. So the immediate result will be heating up the planet.

In turn, if don't use $^{235}$U in a power plant, it will decay by itself with a half-life of 703.8 My, so eventually it will heat up the planet. Using a uranium-based plant in your application could help to cool the planet on a billion-year time scale, which is rather too long to help with climate changes.

For every other source of energy you would need to redo similar analysis.